# Error in PHP/JavaScript website: Notice: trying to access array offset on value of type null

Tags: php

I am so tired and discouraged but am not giving up, I've tried everything again word to word from the tutorial still does not work. I have been trying to fix it for 2 days, I have written the whole code and everything again and still cant fix it. I dont know whats going on. There must be a solution to this. The tutorial video  I am learning from did the exact same thing and it worked! 
The error line is: $style = ($row['opened'] == 'no') ? "background-color: #DDEDFF;" : "";

```
public function getConvosDropdown($data, $limit) {

    $page = $data['page'];
    $userLoggedIn = $this->user_obj->getUsername();
    $return_string = "";
    $convos = array();

    if($page == 1)
        $start = 0;
    else 
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;

    $set_viewed_query = mysqli_query($this->con, "UPDATE messages SET viewed='yes' WHERE user_to='$userLoggedIn'");

    $query = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT user_to, user_from FROM messages WHERE user_to='$userLoggedIn' OR user_from='$userLoggedIn' ORDER BY id DESC");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $user_to_push = ($row['user_to'] != $userLoggedIn) ? $row['user_to'] : $row['user_from'];

        if(!in_array($user_to_push, $convos)) {
            array_push($convos, $user_to_push);
        }
    }

    $num_iterations = 0; //Number of messages checked 
    $count = 1; //Number of messages posted

    foreach($convos as $username) {

        if($num_iterations++ < $start)
            continue;

        if($count > $limit)
            break;
        else 
            $count++;


        $is_unread_query = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT opened FROM messages WHERE user_to='$userLoggedIn' AND user_from='$username' ORDER BY id DESC");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($is_unread_query);
        $style = ($row['opened'] == 'no') ? "background-color: #DDEDFF;" : "";


        $user_found_obj = new User($this->con, $username);
        $latest_message_details = $this->getLatestMessage($userLoggedIn, $username);

        $dots = (strlen($latest_message_details[1]) >= 12) ? "..." : "";
        $split = str_split($latest_message_details[1], 12);
        $split = $split[0] . $dots; 

        $return_string .= "<a href='messages.php?u=$username'> 
                            <div class='user_found_messages' style='" . $style . "'>
                            <img src='" . $user_found_obj->getProfilePic() . "' style='border-radius: 5px; margin-right: 5px;'>
                            " . $user_found_obj->getFirstAndLastName() . "
                            <span class='timestamp_smaller' id='grey'> " . $latest_message_details[2] . "</span>
                            <p id='grey' style='margin: 0;'>" . $latest_message_details[0] . $split . " </p>
                            </div>
                            </a>";
    }


    //If posts were loaded
    if($count > $limit)
        $return_string .= "<input type='hidden' class='nextPageDropdownData' value='" . ($page + 1) . "'><input type='hidden' class='noMoreDropdownData' value='false'>";
    else 
        $return_string .= "<input type='hidden' class='noMoreDropdownData' value='true'> <p style='text-align: center;'>No more messages to load!</p>";

    return $return_string;
}
```

Comment: Where do you set `$row`? The problem is that its value is `null`.

Comment: Can you please post the whole function.

Comment: I just updated it.

Comment: And in the Mysql table i gave 'opened' varchar(3) value, yes or no.

Comment: @boahancockash  What does `var_dump($is_unread_query);` give you? (after the line where you assign it, obviously)

Comment: @Patrick Q , the {var_dump($is_unread_query);} works and it gives the color to the unread messages. But the error comes while I try to send message.. I think the error is something related to the php version. I dont know how to change the code line {$style = ($row['opened'] == 'no') ? "background-color: #DDEDFF;" : "";} in the new version.. this code works in the previous version

Comment: What "previous version"  Your question doesn't mention anything about this.

Comment: I haven't used it in a different version.. the tutorial video im following used it,, and I have done some research about this problem and thats what the problem was with other people for error notice.

Comment: "But the error comes while I try to send message"  If that's the case, then the above code, and specifically the line you mentioned, is _not_ what's throwing the error.  The above code is for displaying a list of messages, not for sending messages.

Comment: I dont get error while sending message... i get error in the dropdown menu,, the sent messages bring this error, while i have no problem sending any messages

Comment: I'm sorry, but you are not being clear about what is happening.  I'm afraid I'm not going to be able to help further.